# Need to create the file name by using folder name and title using XSLT

Tags: json, xml, xslt

I Want to create the link, by using the folder name along with file name with the hypen symbol. If my folder name having items/item.xsl,

My Input XML is:

```
<Settings>
<code>MGT</code>
<url>http://tneb.com</url>
</Settings>
<page/>
<counter>
<enabled>true</enabled>
<text>Management Plan</text>
</counter>
```

XSL I used as(item.xsl) in the folder name(/items):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:json="http://json.org/" xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf" exclude-result-prefixes="#all">

<xsl:template match="Settings">
"Settings": {
<xsl:apply-templates/>
},
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="code">
"code": "<xsl:apply-templates/>",
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="url">
"url": "<xsl:apply-templates/>",
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="page"/>

<xsl:template match="counter">
"counter": {
<xsl:apply-templates/>
},
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="enabled">
"enabled": "<xsl:apply-templates/>",
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text">
"text": "<xsl:apply-templates/>" ,
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Json Output i got as:

```
"Settings": {

"code": "MGT",

"url": "http://tneb.com",

},

"counter": {

"enabled": "true",

"text": "Management Plan ", 

},
```

But i need to create one pdf link in between the settings and counter folder as like below:

```
"Settings": {

"code": "MGT",

"url": "http://tneb.com",

},
pdf: 'files/items-Management-Plan.pdf',

"counter": {

"enabled": "true",

"text": "Management Plan ", 

},
```

I need to create the pdf link, in that **items** denotes folder name and **Management-Plan** denotes the text name from the input file. In between the space of text name fills with hypen symbol in the output.

Please give suggestion regarding this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your first snippet has a not matching `</trackingSettings>`, so it is not XML. That second "JSON" output has an unquoted `pdf` property name, so it is not JSON. As for creating JSON, you have used `version="3.0"` on your stylesheet, if you really use that version then there are better ways to construct JSON as XSLT/XPath 3.0/3.1 have maps and arrays and can serialize them as JSON.

Comment: Now I edited @MartinHonnen. Is this any possible to do by using XSLT for normal conversion apart from json output

Comment: Consider to show us the parent element containing the `Settings` and `counter` element. For that you could write a template doing e.g. `<xsl:apply-templates select="Settings"/>, "pdf" : "files/items-Management-Plan.pdf", <xsl:apply-templates select="counter"/>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the URI of the stylesheet as a variable:

```
<xsl:variable name="stylesheet-uri" as="xs:string" select="base-uri(document(''))"/>
```

Value is e.g. /path/to/items/items.xsl

Then split this into path components:

```
<xsl:variable name="uri-components" as="xs:string+" select="tokenize($stylesheet-uri,'/')">
```

Value is e.g. ("path","to","items","items.xsl")

The folder name is the second last component:

```
<xsl:variable name="folder" as="xs:string" select="$uri-components[count($uri-components) - 1]"/>
```

The second part of the PDF name is the value of the text element with the space characters replaced by hyphens:

```
<xsl:variable name="PDF-name-part" as="xs:string" select="translate(//text/text(), ' ', '-')"/>
```

Finally, put the bits together at the end of your Settings template:

```
<xsl:template match="Settings">
  "Settings": {
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  },

  "pdf:" "<xsl:value-of select="concat('files/',$folder,'-',$PDF-name-part,'.pdf')"/>"

</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add a root template:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="filename" select="replace(counter/text, ' ', '-')" />

    <xsl:apply-templates select="Settings" />

    <!-- The new PDF line -->
    <xsl:text>"pdf": </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat( '&quot;', 'files/items-', $filename, '.pdf', '&quot;', ',&#xA;' )" />       

    <xsl:apply-templates select="Counter" />
</xsl:template>
```

This adds the required line between your Settings and Counter outputs.

Comment: Thanks  @SomeStupid.